# How can I find the root cause of "WARNING: unmet direct dependencies detected for ..."?

Tags: linux-kernel, make, dependencies

When configuring a kernel with `make xxx_defconfig`, I face `WARNING: unmet direct dependencies detected for HOTPLUG`. How do I know where the error is coming from

Error

```
WARNING: unmet direct dependencies detected for HOTPLUG_CPU
  Depends on [n]: SMP [=y] && HOTPLUG && EXPERIMENTAL
  Selected by [y]:
  - PM_SLEEP_SMP [=y] && SMP [=y] && (ARCH_SUSPEND_POSSIBLE [=y] || ARCH_HIBERNATION_POSSIBLE [=y]) && PM_SLEEP [=y]
```